# Select products with top ratings in sql / eloquent ORM

Tags: sql, database, laravel-5, eloquent, rating-system

I have a products table in my db with a one-to-many relationship to reviews table with 5 star rating along as following:

```
# reviews
- id
- product_id
- body
- rating // possible values are 1 to 5
- created_at
- updated_at
```

I have a section in website's home page for top products which I want to display high rated products. So the problem is that I need to write a query with Eloquent ORM to fetch the top 5 highly rated products?

**BTW**, please feel free to suggest plain sql queries and i see if I'm able to convert them to eloquent methods.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT p.*, AVG(r.rating) as average_rating
FROM products as p
INNER JOIN reviews as r ON r.product_id = p.id
GROUP BY p.id
ORDER BY average_rating DESC
LIMIT 5
```

**PS: If you want to order by the sum, just use SUM() instead of average**

I think this should do the trick, this will select all of your products ( this is the end result you want to see ), you inner join them with reviews by product_id. Since you're now inner joining you need to add group by on a specific table otherwise you'll have multiple entries for same product. Order the products the rating DESC, meaning the highest scores are on top. Select the last 5 by limiting your query.

I'm not known with ORM for laravel, I only know Doctrine as ORM.

Comment: thanks for your answer. but it doesn't work I got ORDER BY clause is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column error.

Comment: I edited my post, I ran my code in HeidiSQL and it worked perfectly.

Comment: I added a ", reviews.id" to group by clause and got rid of the error but the query is still wrong because it fetches the products that have digit 5 in their ratings. Meanwhile what it should do is calculating the sum of all of the ratings for each product (1 + 5 + 2 + 4 + 3) and then see which one's sum is greater that the others and return the top 5 one in desc order.

Comment: I edited my answer accordingly, by using AVG of the rating and saving it as a variable you can sort by this one. AVG = average. When you execute the SQL command you'll see that it calculates the average of the ratings foreach product.

Comment: avg() would not work as well because may be a user wrote a review but refused to rate it! so if a product had 8 reviews with 2 null ratings it will be (sum of all ratings) / 8 (which really should be 6).

Comment: Well you could use SUM() instead.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this query for the choose 5 number of the heighest rating :

```
SELECT * FROM reviews ORDER BY rating DESC LIMIT 5;
```

it sort descending with (DESC) and with (LIMIT) you can use 5 rows with heighest rating.
but recommended that rate record into seprate table and when you choose them,use with (left join).may it help you.before,I am sorry if I am not good in english :)))